# Has anyone else seen commands embedded in an ICMP echo request?

Tags: network, ids, malware

My IPS recently detected a type 8 ICMP packet (echo request) with an unusual payload.

The echo request command a fragment of a command that looked like part of a route add. Here's a PCAP of the ICMP data payload.

`.&.1Y..! .b....E.

..x..z. ...)....

....(4.. ......e 

-p ADD 1 72.16.1.

21 MASK  255.255.

255.255  10.18.12

.33..... ..`

The IPS tagged it as Loki tunneling traffic - but it's limited to a single packet. I thought it could be a random grab from memory, but I saw the exact same packet a few days later.

Has anyone seen anything like this before?

Answer (score 4):

Ah, tunneling... SSH, [DNS](http://www.google.com/search?q=dns%20tunneling), [ICMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICMP_tunnel), netcat, custom VPN... you name it. Sometimes known as "give me free wifi" and in other cases as "give me your network."

I don't know that specific payload (as a compromise), but I do know you can put things over ICMP. Take a look at the surrounding packets. This kind of reminds me of the old "ATH+++" gag. It may be a similar exploit for something that's being tossed around at random. I'd like to give more for an answer, but I think I'd need more to go on.

Comment: True, it could be anything and the IPS is blocking it, just concerned it maybe something more and the command looks suspiciously like a rule/acl modification

Comment: Well, much like the ATH+++ thing, there is a risk that somehow the target device would interpret that as a command. (The ATH+++ gag would make improperly guarded dialup modems hang up -- a very cute DOS attack). I don't know the source, the target, the systems you have, etc. It is suspicious payload, though. Perhaps somebody has a console forwarded over ICMP and is issuing that command.

Comment: that would be my guess as well.

Comment: something like this - http://www.cs.uit.no/~daniels/PingTunnel/ ?

Answer (score -1):

the is a bug in recent dhclient implementations, which allows running shell commands remotely.
dunno why it ICMP echo, if its related anyway,

Comment: not sure it's related - I don't think dhclient would be sending out ICMP packets

Comment: @kukkatz, Do you have a pointer to more information about the vulnerability?

Comment: on second thought, i think @Cher Zakalwe is right. @D. W.: i was referring to this: http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/DHCP-client-allows-shell-command-injection-1222805.html